# MEAN Stack: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id"

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean

I´m getting clueless, what to do with an Cast Error in my MEAN application.

I´m pretty new to MEAN and REST... I´ve built a project management application.
Getting all the projects in a list, wasn´t a problem, but now when I´m trying to get a detailed view of one project `GET /projects/:id`, I get this error:
`Cast Error: Vast to ObjectId failed for value :id at path _id`

I´m using a Mongoose Schema for my projects:

```
var mongoose    = require ('mongoose');

var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
        name        : String,  
        description : String,  
        tags        : String,  
        media       : {data: Buffer, contentType: String},  
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now }  
});
```

My Route looks like this:

```
app.get('/projects_view/:id', function (req, res, next) {  
    Project.findById(req.params.id, function (err, project) {  
        if (err) return next (err);  
        res.json(project);  
    }); 
});
```

And last but not least my Angular template for the detail view:

```
<div class="container text-center">
            <div ng-controller="ProjectController">
                    {{ project.name }}
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('ProjectController', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('/projects_view/:id').then(function(res){ 
            $scope.project = res.data;
            });
        });
</script>
```

I´m getting nuts with this error. Hope you can help me.
Kind regards from Germany,
David

**SOLUTION:**
After trying a few things, I managed to make it work. Thanks to plus- and frhd for their help!
So here is the solution, how I could get the ID out of my URL:

```
app.controller('ProjectController',  function($scope, $http){
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $http.get('/projects_view/'+id).success(function(data){ 
                $scope.project = data;
                 });
            });
```

You made my day guys, thank you!

Comment: Are you replacing `:id` with any useful data? It looks like you're just sending out that string, so obviously it is expecting a digestable value for the `_id` field in your mongodb.

Comment: I want the server to get the ID out of my URL, because i´m already on the detail page, e.g.: `http://localhost:3001/projects/5534f541849d5170126a778d`. Am I getting the way `req.params.id` works wrong?

Comment: First, you have to tell angular about the URL and replace `:id` with the desired parameter. You will at least need something like `ngRoute` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$http.get('/projects_view/:id')....
```

This is where your error is. Your ajax call here is sent with the string `:id` hardcoded instead of a real value.

You need to parse the id from your current url and then pass it to the `$http.get` url parameter

Comment: Thank you for your fast explanation, I understand the fact, that I have to parse the ID from my URL and tried it already with `$routeParams`, but still have no clue, why it doesn´t work. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I tried it with something like that, but unfortunatly with no success:   `<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
   
   app.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/projects/:param', {
     controller: "routeController"
    });
   }]);   
   app.controller('routeController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.param = $routeParams.param;
    $http.get('/projects_view/'+param).success(function(data){
     $scope.project = data;
     });
    });   
 </script>`